# Is there a way to add column values in csv matching certain cells?

Tags: powershell, csv, variables, math, sum

I've tried searching but can't seem to find anything really that might assist in this one....
I've got a csv file (inbound from an external company) with contents such as the following:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, etc
Bob, 61, 90, 105
Bob, 88, 21, 37
Bob, 20, 30, 40
Bill, 10, 15, 16
Bill, 90, 80, 70
Carl, 110, 115, 99
Carl, 10, 35, 90
```

What I'd like to do, ideally, is

```
import-csv csvfile | where { $_.Column1 is unique } | autosum column4 | insert newline | total of "bob"
```

So I'm basically finding a unique value in the Column1 (but it may not be a pre-set name, i.e. it could be Bob, or Carl, or Bill, or Emma, etc) - then add the values of the last rows of these, then input a new line below that has the totals??

So it might look like:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, etc
Bob, 61, 90, 105
Bob, 88, 21, 37
Bob, 20, 30, 40
                Bob Totals = 182
Bill, 10, 15, 16
Bill, 90, 80, 70
                Bill Totals = 86
Carl, 110, 115, 99
Carl, 10, 35, 90
                Carl Totals = 189
```

I hope that makes sense & I don't even know if it's possible, it would just save a lot of manual adding from the csv file at present..

Many thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could be a good start:

```
$data = import-csv -path "pathtocsv" -delimiter ","

$unique_names = $data.column1 | select -unique

foreach ($unique_name in $unique_names){
    [int]$currSum = 0
    $currData = $data | ? {$_.column1 -eq $unique_name}
    foreach ($entry in $currData){
        write-host $entry
        $currSum += [int]$($entry.column4.trim())
    }
    write-host "Total for $($entry.column1): $currsum"
}
```

My output:

```
@{Column1=Bob; Column2=61; Column3=90; Column4=105}
@{Column1=Bob; Column2=88; Column3=21; Column4=37}
@{Column1=Bob; Column2=20; Column3=30; Column4=40}
Total for Bob: 182
@{Column1=Bill; Column2=10; Column3=15; Column4=16}
@{Column1=Bill; Column2=90; Column3=80; Column4=70}
Total for Bill: 86
@{Column1=Carl; Column2=110; Column3=115; Column4=99}
@{Column1=Carl; Column2=10; Column3=35; Column4=90}
Total for Carl: 189
```

You'll have to do some formatting, but basically it's working as expected.

Comment: That's great many thanks!!

I've adapted the above to churn out multiple csv files with the addition & will bolt them back together, that was really helpful!!

Thanks :)